# how to create a method to compare attribute values ​of different instanced objects with java

Tags: java, oop

I want to create a method to check whether the value of each attribute of the object is the same or different

here's the description:

> matches(HalamanA1, HalamanA2): public static Compares A1 with A2, returns 1 if equal 0 otherwise. Two pieces object is equal if every attribute value of an object is equal to the attribute value on other objects.

```
class HalamanAlamat {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private int phone;
    private String email;
    private int nbInstance;
    
    HalamanAlamat(){

        this.name = "null";
        this.address = "null";
        this.phone = 0;
        this.email = "null";
        this.nbInstance++;

    }
    
    void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    void setAddress(String address){
        this.address = address;
    }
    
    void setPhone(int phone){
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    
    void setEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }
    
    String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    
    String getAddress(){
        return this.address;
    }
    
    int getPhone(){
        return this.phone;
    }
    
    String getEmail(){
        return this.email;
    }

    public void tostring(){ 

        System.out.println("Nama : " + getName());
        System.out.println("ALamat : " + getAddress());
        System.out.println("No.Handphone : " + getPhone());
        System.out.println("Email : " + getEmail());            
    }
}

public class BukuAlamat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HalamanAlamat halaman1 = new HalamanAlamat();
        halaman1.setName("Rizki okto");
        halaman1.setAddress("Ambarita");
        halaman1.setPhone(629768328);
        halaman1.setEmail("rizok@gmail.com");
        halaman1.tostring();

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Any decent IDE will propose you the implementation of equals and hashCode automatically. With intellij for example you just press Alt + Insert on the class

Comment: What is the issue? The assignment tells you what to do. `public static int matches(HalamanAlamat  HalamanA1, HalamanAlamat HalamanA2) { ... }`

Comment: Is this for a class? Some of this stuff seems odd. Like, using `matches` instead of overriding `equals()`. Having that function return an `int` instead of a `boolean`. Initializing the strings to `"null"`. Having `tostring` instead of overriding `toString()`. That that function prints the data instead of returning a string - shouldn't it be called `print` or something?

Comment: no, the object is in one class

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things to improve concerning this piece of code. The equals method your question requests is at the end of this answer, but you might want to read it if you actually want to learn coding instead of copy-pasting.

1. Use access parameters. Just as in the BukuAlmet class, the HalamanAlamat class should have access types for every method and the class itself if not for the specific purpose of making a class package-private (and it doesn't look like it should be, if the class is modifierless for the purpose of staying in the same file, you might want to split the file up, since this isn't a good practice.)
2. Initializing ints to 0 is unneccessary since all primitive types have a default value of 0 except for booleans which are false by default. Initializing strings to "null" is also unneccessary, when printing out an uninitialized string, "null" will be printed anyways.
3. Do not use this. for everything. This should be used in cases like this:

```
private int ID;
public void setID(int ID) {
   this.ID = ID;
}
```

Where not using this results in a compiler error.
It can be used for readability in certain cases but when using it that often, it only takes readability away and might even cause bugs in debugging tools in some rare edgecases.

4. Do not write a tostring() method! Override the Object.toString method instead. (By adding `@Override` in the line above the method) The reason for this is A: one typo can make you call the wrong method and debugging that is a nightmare. B: If you have a tostring method, toString is redundant. C: Not using camelCase when working with other developers is like putting a whole file in one line. Works but. . . NO!
5. Why do you have this int nbInstance? It is always 1 because it is not static. I guess you want to count how many instances of the class you have, but to do this, that int has to be static (and therefore not be called by this.nbInstance!)
6. Here you got you CopyPaste Exercise (a little different that you asked for, so you have to understand it to use it):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(HalamanAlamat cmp) {
    boolean equ = name.equals(cmp.getName());
    equ |= address.equals(cmp.getAddress());
    equ |= email.equals(cmp.getEmail());
    return equ && phone == cmp.getPhone();
}
```